# jQuery - failing to submit username password and causing 401 unauthorized

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome, chromium

When i open using the Google chrome browser this url `http://www.site.nl/a/b/c/d/e?niss=f`, it first ask for username password:

[image]

Manually when i put the username password i get some data.

Now, using jQuery how can i submit that username password? following is not working, always after submit its failing with "401 unauthorized"

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://www.site.nl/a/b/c/d/e?niss=f",
    dataType: 'json',
    async: false,
    headers: {
      "Authorization": "Basic Username1:password1234"
    },
    data: '{ "test" }',
    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR){
      console.log(data, textStatus, jqXHR);
    }
  });  
});
```

Comment: Do you send the password in plain text or Base64 encoded in the Authorization header?

Comment: You may want to check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5507234/how-to-use-basic-auth-with-jquery-and-ajax) thread.

Comment: PLAIN text password.

Answer (score 0):

Please try following code

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://www.site.nl/a/b/c/d/e?niss=f",
    dataType: 'json',
    async: false,
    data: '{ "test" }',
    beforeSend: function(xhr)
    {
      xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', make_base_auth("Username1", "password1234"));
    },
    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR){
      console.log(data, textStatus, jqXHR);
    }
  });  
});

function make_base_auth(user,password)
{
  var tok = user + ':' + password;
  var hash = btoa(tok);
  return "Basic " + hash;
} // ends
```

Comment: Its still same failure. please see the failure details, check line 10:  http://paste.ubuntu.com/16356592/

Comment: `Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 401` - Always failing, can you please tell why? basically it works and i get XML data while using from web browser

Comment: Try specifying content-type in header and check, If you have access of domain then check if CORS is enabled or not